# Algoritmo de ordenação

Tags: java, classificação

Montei um método que, para três valores, ele deve exibir os três em ordem crescente.
Porém, ele só funciona se os três valores (`v1`, `v2` e `v3`) forem diferentes.
Caso haja dois ou três valores iguais, ele mantém o valor da variável `medioValor` como foi inicializada.

Tem como resolver isso sem modificar muito a estrutura original do programa?

Segue o código:

```
public static void ordenarNumeros(int v1, int v2, int v3)
{
    int valores[] = {v1, v2, v3};

    int maiorValor = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int menorValor = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){        
        if (valores[i] > maiorValor)
            maiorValor = valores[i];
        if (valores[i] < menorValor)
            menorValor = valores[i];
    }

    int medioValor = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        if (valores[i] < maiorValor && valores[i] > menorValor)
            medioValor = valores[i];
    }

    System.out.printf("\n\tOs valores, em ordem crescente, são: %d - %d - %d.\n", menorValor, medioValor, maiorValor);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Não existe um valor médio se temos apenas 2 valores diferentes, ou apena 1 valor .

Ex :
se os valores forem [5,10,10] , qual o valor médio?

aproveitando pra te indicar uma lib para manipulação de arrays

```
import java.util.Arrays;

   ...
   
int[] arr = { 13, 7, 6} ;               
Arrays.sort(arr); // ordena o array
```

Agora se você quer o valor que ficou no meio do array pegue o index[1]

```
maiorValor = arr[2]
menorValor = arr[0]
medioValor = arr[1]
```

Comment: Olá! Valeu pela resposta. Entendo o que você está dizendo, porém, se eu lhe desse os valores 10, 20 e 10, para colocá-los em ordem crescente, poderíamos escrever 10 - 10 - 20, não concorda? É isso que eu gostaria que o programa fizesse... E obrigado pela dica dos arrays - certamente vai ajudar bastante! Ainda assim, fiquei com a pulga atrás da orelha. Queria saber se, daquele jeito que eu estava fazendo (ou de um jeito similar, isto é, sem usar métodos prontos do Java), teria como escrever, por exemplo, 10 - 10 - 20 para `v1 = 10`, `v2 = 20` e `v3 = 10`, por exemplo.